# Can't connect to MySQL @127.0.0.1 installed via Homebrew

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, datagrip

Trying to set up my local database in DataGrip. I installed `mysql@5.7` via Homebrew. I did `brew services list` and it confirmed that `mysql@5.7` is started.

I try to add this database with the following settings:

```
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 3306
user: root
pass: (null)
```

It keeps telling me connection refused. I'm not sure why. I've installed the most recent MySQL driver in DataGrip as well, which did not correct the issue.

I've also checked `my.cnf` and the IP is set to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Is the port open? Or tried with `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`? Also do you have `bind-address` setting in your `my.cnf`?

Comment: Yes I had bind-address, I fixed it by uninstalling and removing leftover files from a previous MySQL install, then doing a clean @5.7 install.

Comment: So its already solved?

Comment: yes it is. will post answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had old files from a previous MySQL install that was conflicting with `@5.7`.

I had to just uninstall all versions, `rm` all of leftover files, then re-install `@5.7` and it worked great.

Comment: That was my problem too. I had used the installer and then decided to use homebrew. Even though I used the uninstaller there was something remaining. Here is the list I used https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x